# Using xdebug with drush command

Tags: composer-php, xdebug, drush, ddev

I have two Drupal codebases. On the first, I can hit a specific breakpoint through both the browser and through a drush command. On the second, I can hit the breakpoint only through the browser. The drush command finishes successfully without hitting the breakpoint. I can't find any meaningful difference between the two installations.

Local development on Windows 10 home
Docker toolbox
DDEV v1.14.2
Composer version 1.10.5
IDE is VSCode, launch.json file is identical between the two
Drush Launcher *not* installed

**The good one:**
c:...\d8-04-28>ddev exec drush status
 Drupal version   : 8.8.5
 Site URI         : https://d8-04-28.ddev.site
 DB driver        : mysql
 DB hostname      : db
 DB port          : 3306
 DB username      : db
 DB name          : db
 Database         : Connected
 Drupal bootstrap : Successful
 Default theme    : bartik
 Admin theme      : seven
 PHP binary       : /usr/bin/php7.3
 PHP config       : /etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini
 PHP OS           : Linux
 Drush script     : /var/www/html/vendor/drush/drush/drush
 Drush version    : 10.2.2
 Drush temp       : /tmp
 Drush configs    : /var/www/html/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml
                    /var/www/html/drush/drush.yml
 Install profile  : standard
 Drupal root      : /var/www/html/web
 Site path        : sites/default
 Files, Public    : sites/default/files
 Files, Temp      : /tmp

**The bad one**
c:...\d8-06-08>ddev exec drush status
 Drupal version   : 8.8.5
 Site URI         : https://d8-06-08.ddev.site
 DB driver        : mysql
 DB hostname      : db
 DB port          : 3306
 DB username      : db
 DB name          : db
 Database         : Connected
 Drupal bootstrap : Successful
 Default theme    : bartik
 Admin theme      : seven
 PHP binary       : /usr/bin/php7.3
 PHP config       : /etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini
 PHP OS           : Linux
 Drush script     : /usr/local/bin/drush
 Drush version    : 10.2.2
 Drush temp       : /tmp
 Drush configs    : /var/www/html/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml
                    /var/www/html/drush/drush.yml
 Install profile  : standard
 Drupal root      : /var/www/html/web
 Site path        : sites/default
 Files, Public    : sites/default/files
 Files, Temp      : /tmp

On the bad one only, after turning on xdebug in ddev, the PHP config line in drush status changes to:
 PHP config       : /tmp/bApEy0

I'm pretty sure my debugging problem has to do with the drush script line in drush status, but I can't find anything to change that affects that line.

Any ideas to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

I note that the first one shows "Drush script : /var/www/html/vendor/drush/drush/drush" and the second one "Drush script : /usr/local/bin/drush". But inside the container, /usr/local/bin/drush is "drush launcher". So there's definitely a difference in how this is happening.

- When debugging drush (or any command line script), execute it the simplest way possible, which is inside the container, so `ddev ssh` and then run drush.
- But be specific about what you're running, don't use the drush launcher in the container, run the site-installed drush by running /var/www/html/vendor/bin/drush - that way there aren't extra layers of scripts running extra layers of drush.
- Nothing about drush or drush launcher on your host system would be relevant, because everything is happening inside the container.
- Remember to `ddev xdebug on` before debugging.
- Please review "PHPStorm and Command-Line Debugging" in the docs at https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/step-debugging/#step-debugging-with-ddev-and-xdebug and also Matt Glaman's excellent blog about [xdebug over the command line](https://glamanate.com/blog/xdebug-over-command-line-ddev)

Comment: Using your suggestions, I have it working now. But that leads me to another question. Why did the "good one" work?

Comment: It looks (from AFAR) like you had composer correctly installed in the project on the "good one" and not on the "bad one".

Answer (score 0):

This is because

> Drush Launcher, like Composer automatically disables Xdebug by default. -- https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher#xdebug-compatibility

- As the doc suggests, you can run `DRUSH_ALLOW_XDEBUG=1 drush [command]` to trigger xdebug,
- or run `./vender/bin/drush [command]` to trigger xdebug (without using the launcher)
- or put `DRUSH_ALLOW_XDEBUG=1` in your env variable, so normal `drush [command]` can also trigger xdebug. [Here is an example](https://github.com/skyred/drupal-devcontainers/commit/6868c436d0f4c96a3128536fd26a49c303c2ea53)

Answer (score 0):

If you run a PHP script then VSCode will be able to debug with no problems. What I did was locate the php file for drush and executed it with PHP. For instance, to debug **drush cr** I do:

> php vendor/drush/drush/drush.php cr

(Make sure you place a breakpoint and start the debugger first)